# Importação de classes no Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, import

Tenho tres arquivos .py em meu diretorio: *`Banco.py`, `app.py`, `Usuarios.py`*.

O meu `app.py` contém a importação do Tkinder que estou usando no codigo e por aqui que inicio toda a minha view e nela importo a classe `Usuarios.py` da seguinte maneira:

```
#Arquivo app.py
from .Usuarios import *
from tkinter import *

class Application:
def __init__(self, master=None):
```

No arquivo `Usuario.py` contém toda as execuções do SQL para insert, delete, update e select, e nesse arquivo importo o arquivo `Banco.py`, segue:

```
#Arquivo Usuarios.py
from .Banco import Banco

class Usuarios():
    def __init__(self, idusuario=0, nome="", telefone="", email="", usuario="", senha="" ):
```

Em seguida no arquivo do Banco apenas dou o import no sqlite para sua utilização, segue:

```
#Arquivo Banco.py
import sqlite3

class Banco():
    def __init__(self):
```

O problema surge quando executo o app.py que me retorna o erro seguinte erro:

> /usr/bin/python3.6 "/home/owi/Documents/PycharmProjects/Tkinder
>   examples/app.py" Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/owi/Documents/PycharmProjects/Tkinder examples/app.py", line 1,
>   in 
>       from .Usuarios import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.Usuarios'; '**main**' is not a package
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Gostaria de entender qual o problema relacionado ao main que não esta correto já que todos as classes contem `def __ini__`.

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é botar todo mundo em uma [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Estruture a pasta do seu projeto assim:

```
meuprojeto/
    __init__.py            
    app.py                         
    Usuario.py
    Banco.py
```

Sendo que `__init__.py` é um arquivo sem nada. Quando uma página possui um `__init__.py`, o Python sabe que trata-se de uma package. Daí você poderá importar bibliotecas assim:

```
from meuprojeto import Usuarios

Usuarios.funcao()
```

Ou ainda:

```
import meuprojeto as mp

mp.Usuarios.funcao()
```

Eu não gosto que nada seja implícito no meus programas, então costumo a dar preferência para o segundo método.

Lembrando ainda que a maneira idiomática de nomear modulos em python é usando apenas letras minusculas, e.g.: `usuarios`

Comment: Faltou dizer que fazendo isso - de colocar o projeto num package, a sintaxe do AP, de importar os arquivos prefixando-os com um "." vai passar a funcionar.